# Java split using regex lookahead - character not followed by character

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to split the string to the substings in order to sort them to quoted and not quoted ones. The single quote character is used as a separator, and two single quotes represents an escape sequence and means that they shall not be used for splitting.

For example:

```
"111 '222''22' 3333"
```

shall be splitted as

```
"111", "222''22", "3333"
```

no matter with or without whitespaces.

So, I wrote the following code, but it does not work. Tried lookbehind with `"\\'(?<!\\')"` as well, but with no success. Please help

```
    String rgxSplit="\\'(?!\\')";
    String text="";
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\""+rgxSplit+"\"");
    text=s.nextLine();
    while(!text.equals(""))
    {
        String [] splitted=text.split(rgxSplit);
        for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                System.out.println("+" + splitted[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("-" + splitted[i]);
            }
        }
        text=s.nextLine();
    }
```

Output:

```
$ java ParseTest
"\'(?!\')"
111 '222''22' 3333
+111
-222'
+22
- 3333
```

Comment: Just use split and combine when you get a zero length field.

Comment: What about three single quotes? Four?

Comment: Try this: `"(?<!')'(?!')"`

Comment: There is no need to escape a single quote within a regex.

Comment: @Tomalak In case of 3 ', first two shall be grouped together, and the last one shall be used as the separator

Comment: @RealSkeptic Do you believe this knowledge will help me in this particular case? )

Comment: @MariaDeleva Does not work for "111 '''222''22' '333' 444"

Comment: @BbIKTOP Knowledge never only applies to a particular case. Learning to use your tools correctly is part of the job.

Comment: @Tomalak I knew somebody will write that ))
Ok, the extra escape does not affect anything, so it's not the case to remember unnecessary things.

Comment: Nonsense. Escaping characters that don't need escaping is voodoo programming. Don't do voodoo programming and try to justify it by "but it does not do any harm".

Comment: @Tomalak Nonsense. noop is just an op. Nothing wrong or voodo.
Ok, I didn't ask about that, isn't it? )

Comment: You come to Stackoverflow to get advice, you get advice. I'm not sure what the problem with that is. "Don't be sloppy" is pretty damn good advice.

Comment: I'm just trying to explain that "no operation" operator does nothing wrong and has nothing common to voodo ) It's like ';' operator in C or 90 operator in x86.
I exactly described what advice I'm looking for, don't understand people who give advises they never been asked for. Let's stop that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should split on a single quote (when it is not doubled), and in the case of three consecutive, it will group the first two and will split on the third.

```
String [] splitted=text.split("(?<!') *' *(?!')|(?<='') *' *");
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it's working! Will test further )

Comment: Could you please tell me why did you change the first version?

Comment: This version: `(?<!')'(?!')|(?<='')'` only accounts for the quotes, without the spaces. You can use it like that, and trim the spaces after. Or you can use the above version which removes any spaces before/after the delimiter single quote as well.

Comment: Thank you! Got it already ) The only voodo thing (as mentioned by Tomalak) is, why the simple split using lookahead "'(?!')" does not work. I just don't understand why is it necessary to explicitly describe both cases and to use lookbehind.

Comment: This fails for more than 3 consecutive single quotes.

Comment: Because if you simply use lookahead it will not match `'` followed by a `'`, however, it will match `'`, following a `'` (i.e., it will match the second `'`, but not the first `'`).

Comment: @Tomalak, if the OP describes whether it is possible to have more than 3 consecutive single quotes and what should be done in these cases, I will update the regex. If there will be no occurrences of more than 3 consecutive single quotes, it will be pointless to make a more complex regex.

Comment: Direct quote from the question: *"two single quotes represents an escape sequence"*, this implies that four single quotes are possible.

Comment: `(?<!')'(?!')|(?<!')(?<='')'(?!')|(?<='')'(?='')` This will work for 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 consecutive single quotes. If it is 2 or 4, it won't split, if it is 3, groups the first 2, splits on the third, if it is 5, splits on the third. But then we enter a very tricky territory: what if we want to split on the 5th in some cases and on the third in others? How would we determine which case it is?

Comment: There we get to the core of why using regex for parsing is a bad idea. The posed problem is trivial for a parser. To get it correct with regular expressions ranges from "disproportionately difficult" to "impossible", depending on which regex dialect is being used. One with variable-length look-behinds helps, but Java does not support them.

Comment: The question was not about parsers. The question is, why my regex is not working. I really still don't understand that/

Comment: When you have two single quotes and you are searching for a single quote, you have 2 possible matches. When you say "A single quote cannot be followed by a single quote", the first match will be invalid, as the first single quote is followed by a single quote. However, the second single quote is technically not followed by a single quote (you do not have a third single quote in the sequence), so it is a match. Each single quote is reviewed independently of the other. So it should neither be followed, nor be following another single quote.

Answer (score 0):

To split on single apostrophes use look arounds both sides of the apostrophe:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" *(?<!')'(?!') *");
```

See [live demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/pr135v).

Comment: That would also split where 2 consecutive single quotes are present and the OP doesn't want this.

Comment: Still wrong but close:
Enter regex:  *(?<!')'(?!') *  
" *(?<!')'(?!') *"  
Enter text: 111 '''222''22' '333' 444  
+111 '''222''22  
-  
+333  
-444

Comment: Why not `"11 '''''''222''2' 33"`? If you allow unlimited apostrophes, regex can't do it. You needs proper language parser.

Comment: That's what the reg expressions are invented for )))   The answer above is working fine, thank you!

Comment: @bbik actually the answer above doesn't work for an arbitrary number of consecutive apostrophes, as demonstrated in [this live demo](https://ideone.com/EIEu1H). Regex doesn't *parse*, it *matches*. Specifically, regex doesn't handle nesting or arbitrary escape depths etc

Comment: It works just fine: `"(?<!')'(?!')|(?<='')'"
Enter text: 11 '''''''222''22' 3333
+11 ''
-
+
-
+
-222''22
+ 3333`
It matches, sure. And matches right in this case.

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrary numbers of single quotes either, e.g. it fails for `111 '222'''''22' 3333`

Comment: Well. Let me explain it a bit further. It, surely, matches. And it shall match not an _arbitrary_ depths but one by one. Just imagine, that 5 characters are 3+2 and so on. It's a kind of DFA, the finite state machine, it actually works step by step, not with the whole string as you could think looking at String#split

Comment: @toma not sure who you're directing that comment to, but (AFAIK) apostrophe === single quote, ie that's my point.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lA0wP0/1 As far as I can see this should match at the single quote before the last group or 2's, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Tomalak Java version does the job: 
`"(?<!')'(?!')|(?<='')'"
Enter text: 111 '222'''''22' 3333
+111
-222''
+
-
+22
- 3333`